# Hunspell - How to specify case-insensitivity for spell check in dic or aff file

Tags: hunspell

I'm creating a custom spell check engine implementation using an open-source hunspell dic/aff set as a starting point.  After an inordinate amount of hacking, googling, etc., I copied a flag set that *appears* to result in case-insensitive searching (e.g., the spell check passes  "Word" as well as "word", when only "word" is present in the dic file). Problem is, I have no idea WHY this works, and I can't find anything online or in the files indicating how case is treated.  The syntax in my dic that works is:

```
word/1   1
```

Without these flags, case handling is strict.

I am remiss to implement a "solution" I can't explain.  Any one have any idea how to specify case handling in a dic/aff set so that I can figure out what's actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, entries in `.dic` files are presumed to be case-insensitive, and thus given the entry `word`, all of the following should be returned as correctly spelled: *word, Word, WORD*.

If you want to restrict words to a single casing, you'll need define a case sensitive flag in your `.aff` file:

```
KEEPCASE X
```

Where `X` is a one or two letter flag or a number (based on your FLAG setting)

So, if I only wanted to allow *John* (but not *john* or *JOHN*), I could then put in my `.dic`file the following entry:

```
John/X
```

I do not know why the `/1` is allowing for case-insensitive results, especially because that line is a bad format (the only thing that should follow after spaces is a field id and its information, for example, `po:noun`)

You said you're creating a custom engine, so the problem is going to be in your engine, not in the `.dic/.aff` files.

Comment: if there is `AF` then `/1` matches the first `AF` rule